# Enabling Keyboard Media Key Events on MacOS

Tags: macos, launchd

Environment: Fresh Install of MacOS 11.1

I wanted to disable Apple Music / iTunes from responding to keyboard media keys (previous, pause, start) so I ran the following line through `launchctl`:

```sh
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist 2> /dev/null
```

However, this setting is preventing ANY application from responding to media keys.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to apply this selectively for iTunes / Apple Music?
2. If not, how can I re-enable this setting (for all applications)?

So far, I have tried:

```sh
# In
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist

# Out
# Load failed: 5: Input/output error
# Does the response need to be loaded onto a stream?

# In
launchctl start /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
# Out
# No Change, No Errors
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: This just hides the error messages, it doesn't solve the problem.